# CUDA and sparse arrays

Tags: performance-tuning, cuda

Is there a way to use the CUDA functions (like CUDADot and so on) when we are dealing with SparseArrays? I found some answers to similar questions but they are extremely old (around five years ago) and not very easy to implement. Hence, I was wondering whether something changed in the meantime.

Comment: CUDA in _Mathematica_ is dead. (Some say, it was never really alive.) So do not expect any changes in the near future (or at all). And to my knowledge, there has never been any built-in CUDA support for sparse arrays.

Comment: Thank you, @HenrikSchumacher. A sad truth but btter to know :-D